# Change image position depending on screen resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsive

I have recently been learning about responsive web design. What I am trying to achieve is presented on the images below, one is for how the website should look like on desktop, and the other one is for mobiles devices.
So as you can see, there are four boxes. After clicking the box, in the textbox you will see some text referring to that box. What I have been thinking about is how to deal with this layout. Is it just the Media Queries and different CSS styling depending on the screen resolution? Or should i somehow (jquery?) switch the elements order in the DOM? Im not sure how to handle this. Thanks for any advice!

[image: Desktop]

[image: Smartphone]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @D.Fraga's comment, the css `@media` rule could be used as follows:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) 
    /* css for large device */
    /*                      */
}


@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     /* css for small device */
     /*                      */
}
```

You have 2 sets of css, one for rendering larger devices, the other for smaller.

You may also considering using javascript `screen.width` with some sort of framework (i.e. angularjs) to dynamically render DOM elements based on screen size (though I *highly* recommend the former).

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with css only:

```
@media (max-width: 420px){
 /* Your Code */
}
```

Study `@media` of CSS

Answer (score 0):

If you use these **media queries** for different screen views, maybe your problem will be solved.

Media query for large devices like laptops, desktops with screen size 1025px to 1280px

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {

  //Your css here

}
```

Media query for tablets, mobile (Landscape Layout) with screen size 481px to 767px

```
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {

  //Your css here

}
```

Media query for smartphone mobile (Portrait Layout) with screen size 320px to 479px

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

          // Your css here

        }
```